# populate multidimensional array from MySQL query

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I am trying to create multidimensional array from MySQL query

**Query:**

```
    $STH = $DBH->query( "SELECT  value, o_ID, oName, date,  
                         DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %m %Y') as FDate,
                         DATE_FORMAT(tsTime, '%H:%i') as FTime
                         FROM test tst
                         LEFT JOIN object o
                         ON  tst.o_ID =o.oID
                         WHERE DATE(date) = '$date'
                         ORDER BY FDate, FTime, oName ASC");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Loop:**

```
$returnValue = array();
$data = array();

while ( $row = $STH->fetch() ) {

   $returnValue[$row['oName']] = 
       array(
         $data[] = array(
              'time' => $row['FTime'], 'value' => $row['value']
          )
       );
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"objectA":[{"time":"23:55","value":"15"}],"objectB":[{"time":"23:55","value":"15.90"}],..}
```

how can I put all values in $data array?

**Desired output:**

```
{"objectA":[{"time":"01:00","value":"15"},{"time":"02:00","value":"11"},{"time":"03:00,"value":"16"}],"objectB":[{"time":""01:00","value":"12"},{"time":""02:00","value":"25"},{"time":""03:00","value":"5"}],..}
```

Comment: try replacing while loop as `while ( $row = $STH->fetch() ) {

   $returnValue[$row['oName']] = 
       array(
              'time' => $row['FTime'], 'value' => $row['value']
          );
      
}`

Comment: it will return it like this: `[{"time":"01:00","value":"15"},{"time":"02:00","value":"11"},....]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$returnValue = array();
while ( $row = $STH->fetch() )
{
   if (!$returnValue[$row['oName']])
   {
       $returnValue[$row['oName']] = array();
   }
   $returnValue[$row['oName']][]= array(
          'time' => $row['FTime'], 'value' => $row['value']
      );
}
```

That should give you what you want.

The difference here is that, if the `oName`-key doesn't exits, I create it, and assign it a new, empty array, then I add a new assiciative array to that array. 
When the `oName` of row N already has a matching key, I'm not going to reassign that key, but I'm just going to push an extra array to that key.

Comment: for the first few rows it says `Notice: Undefined index:objectA in...,Notice: Undefined index:objectB in... ` but then is ok ` {"objectA":[{"time":"00:00","value":"15.90"},{"time":"01:0","value":"15.80"}...`

Comment: @inTry: just initiate `$returnValue` and assign it an array, if the notices still appear, try using `array_key_exists` or `empty` instead of `!$returnValue[]` in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while ( $row = $STH->fetch() ) {
    $returnValue[] = array(
       'time' => $row['FTime'], 'value' => $row['value']
      );
    }
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in... `